# Flutter bloc fill initial state with data

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have a question about bloc correct code placement so to say.
So as bloc stands for business logic component I've moved business logic (like processing data methods) inside class. So now there are 2 methods one for getting and second for saving data.
Next, I have my component which within `AddInitial` should show loading, then fire bloc saying "hey, I need data here". Is it correct or it's antipattern? Code looks like this.

```
BlocBuilder<AddBloc, AddState>(
  buildWhen: (previous, current) {
    // code is ommited
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is ExpensesLoaded || state is CategoryChanged) {
      // code is ommited
    } else if (state is ExpensesLoading) {
      return getProgressSpinner();
    } else if (state is AddInitial) {
      // is it ok? If it's antipattern please give an advise how to do it correctly
      context.bloc<AddBloc>().add(CategoryChange([category]));
      return getProgressSpinner();
    } else {
      print('Bloc Loaded. Nothing to show inside Month Expenses...');
      return Container();
    }
  }
```

Question about `context.bloc<AddBloc>().add(CategoryChange([category]));`. Is it antipattern? How this should be done?

By the way when it looks like this. Next time when I add `CategoryChange` event to bloc (which will yields `CategoryChanged` state) builder from above doesn't react for some reason...

Thanks!

I'm using Flutter 1.22.3, flutter_bloc: 6.1.0

Answer (score 1):

> How this should be done?

When you know your initial state of your Bloc when you create it (lets say a static list with the first entry pre-selected by default) then you can use the Bloc constructor that takes that initial state as a parameter.

If you don't know what the correct initial state is, because it is dynamic (lets say a list of locations loaded from a service based on GPS that the user has to agree to get by button click because it costs money) then it's perfectly fine to have an "empty" or "uninitialized" or "waitingForUserInteraction" state. After all, that *is* the state of your program then.

> By the way when it looks like this. Next time when I add CategoryChange event to bloc (which will yields CategoryChanged state) builder from above doesn't react for some reason

The bloc finds out whether to send out a new state change by comparing the old and new state. If you want to modify the default behavior, you can make sure the two states compare as equal (or not). The easiest way to do that is derive your states from `Equatable` in the package [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) like this:

```
@immutable
abstract class SomeState extends Equatable {
  final String importantChange;
  final String unimportantChange;

  const SomeState(this.importantChange, this.unimportantChange);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [importantChange]; 
}
```

Only listing one field in the "props" list means only this is compared when comparing for equality. If `importantChange` is equal, the states are considered equal (and will not be emitted from the Bloc). Two states having the same `importantChange` but different `unimportantChange` are considered the same.

Comment: Thanks. Here a have a little bit different logic. Actually it's mix of all you wrote. I want to show screen with few completed widgets and one widget will start with loader (at same time db request will be fired). After db will response the relevant widget should be updated